How to avoid adding word before matched line when word already exists
I created the following sed in order to add the python command exit() before the line LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD in the file yumrpm.py
 sed -i  '0,/LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD/s//exit()\n&/' yumrpm.py

Example (after we run the above sed syntax)
exit()
LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD = "yum list all" 

The problem is when we run the sed again and in this case we get an additional exit().
Example:
exit()
exit()
LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD = "yum list all" 

What do I need to add in the sed command in order to avoid adding exit() when exit() already exists before the line LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD?
NOTE - the solution should be inside sed , we dont want to add grep before sed in order to verify if exit() exists

Dupe is definitely not correct since this problem is asking to avoid adding exit() when exit() already exists before the line LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD not anywhere in the file.

For this task, an awk suits more than sed. Consider this awk solution:
cat file

exit()
some line
LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD = "yum list 1"
exit()
LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD = "yum list 2"
LIST_FEW_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD = "yum list 3"
exit()

awk '!ext && /LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD/ {print "exit()"}
{ext = /^exit\(\)/} 1' file

exit()
some line
exit()
LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD = "yum list 1"
exit()
LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD = "yum list 2"
LIST_FEW_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD = "yum list 3"
exit()

This awk commands searches for a line starting with ^exit() and if it finds then sets a flag ext to 1 otherwise sets it to 0.
Then it prints exit() before a line ONLY if ext is not set to 1 it matches a line starting with LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD.

the question is about sed not awk

That's the reason why I started my answer with For this task, an awk suits more than sed

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '/^LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD/!h;//!b;x;/^exit()/{x;h;b};x;i\exit()' file

If a line does not start LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD make a copy in the hold space.
If a line does not start LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD, perform no further processing (implicitly print the line).
Otherwise, swap to the hold space.
If the hold space starts exit(), swap back to the pattern space, make a copy of the pattern space in the hold space and perform no further processing (implicitly print the line).
Otherwise, swap back to the pattern space, insert a line exit() and perform no further processing (implicitly print then line).
N.B. This always inserts a line exit() before the desired pattern if exit() is not present. If there are multiple such desired pattern lines and only the first should be preceded by exit() use:
sed '/^LIST_ALL_SELECT_TOOL_PACKAGES_CMD/!h;//!b;x;/^exit()/{x;b};x;i\exit()' file

